# Accessing redis from a docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-elasticache

Simple question - I hope.

I am trying to communicate to a redis instance running on Amazon elastic cache from a docker container on an amazon ec2 machine. I can connect without problems to the redis instance from the ec2 machine host (which would seem to indicate that this is not a security/ports problem) but I get a timeout when trying to connect from within the docker container. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your environment? Are you using beanstalk? If so, single container platform or multi-container? If not, what else are you using?

Comment: I'm running into a similar error: `[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`. Works fine locally, and from an EC2 instance, but not from inside a docker container.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, how did you solved it?